# Should I include zeros in downside beta calculation?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk

Downside beta is the beta coefficient for an asset and a benchmark restricting benchmark returns to be less than a given value. Let’s assume zero for simplicity.

We have:

[image]

If we have returns in period 1, 2, and 3, such that:

Asset: 5%, 3%, 8%

Benchmark: 4%, 2%, -1%

Would I run the beta using:

a) covar(5%, 3%; 4%, 2%)/var(4%, 2%)

or,

b) covar(5%, 3%, 0%; 4%, 2%, 0%)/var(4%, 2%, 0%)

With downside deviation we typically include the zeros for points which failed the positive/negative test, so unsure here.

Comment: My interpretation of $var(r_m|r_m<\mu_m)$ is that you must include in the calculation of the variance only those elements that satisfy the inequality $r_m<\mu_m$ and exclude the others (not replace them by zero).

Comment: And then match those with the corresponding asset returns? Or option a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional notation is indeed a bit confusing for those who do not spend a lot of time with mathematics.  Downside beta is computed simply by taking only those data rows for which we see underperformance, and then doing the regular beta calculation.

So, for example, if you have percent returns like

| Asset | Benchmark |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 |
| -2 | 2 |
| 8 | -1 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 |

Then the average market benchmark return is 2.8, so the rows you include are

| Asset | Benchmark |
| --- | --- |
| -2 | 2 |
| 8 | -1 |
| 3 | 1 |

and the calculation is $\beta^- = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(\{-2,8,3\};\{2,-1,1\})}{\mathrm{Var}(\{2,-1,1\})}$ or -4.82.  One does *not* insert zeros.

(Note: with this data our "upside" beta is -0.75.)

As an aside, downside beta is a really excellent risk measure to consider, and I am glad to see it receiving your attention.

**Edits (per comments by @Henry Walter):**

(A) Fixed Variance in denominator to be benchmark variance

(B) Fixed row choices

Comment: I am horribly confused now. Why did you choose 2, 6, and 5 for your benchmark returns. The benchmark values less than the average benchmark return are 2, -1, and 1. Also you are dividing by var(asset values) when it should be var(benchmark values). Am I mistaken?

Comment: Edit* You are computing in a very different way than the formula describes. The formula wants us to only use pairs where benchmark return is less than the average benchmark return. You are taking pairs where the asset return is less than the benchmark return in that period. Are these not two entirely different things? Also you divide by var(asset returns) and not var(benchmark returns). I think your answer was submitted in error. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ouch, thank you for catching the mistakes @Henry Walter!  And indeed, the rows we need to select are market underperformance, not asset underperformance.

Comment: Thank you! Is it correct to only interpret rises in benchmark returns for upside beta, and declines in benchmark returns for downside beta? For example, for upside beta of 2 we say “1% rise in benchmark means 2% rise in asset.” For downside beta of 2 we say “1% decline in benchmark means 2% decline in asset.” This feels weird to me since it seems like you can interpret increases and decreases for upside beta, and do the same for downside beta… since our “downside” is where benchmark returns < average benchmark return. Make sense what I’m asking?